# General questions for registering an application in Lync UCWA Endpoint ID

Tags: uuid, lync, ucwa

Iam Using Lync Server with UCWA 1.0 and have several questions about the Endpoint ID.

1. Must i register an Endpoint ID for every user how is using my application, or have i to register one Enpoint ID for every one application?
2. Is it possible to use a Endpoint ID for more than one users?
3. How many Endpoint IDs can a single user register?
4. How long is a Endpoint ID valid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Specifically related to UCWA for On-Premises**

1. The Endpoint ID is just a string ('*blablabla*' is a valid Endpoint ID), you don't have to register it anywhere. Trust is given to your application via *Set-CsWebServiceConfiguration*
2. Yes
3. I think there is no documented limit, but should follow the number of max active endpoints the user can have (including logged in clients). Anyway, also in relation to question above: if you create two UCWA applications for the same user and same endpoint ID, you'll receive a conflict, and one application will be terminated
4. As per first answer: in this scenario Endpoint ID is just any valid string, and not registered anywhere with the server (thus no validity expiration)

Comment: Thanks for response

Comment: you're welcome. Please verify and confirm especially about item 2. I'm pretty sure, but it has been a while since when I did the tests I based by answer on!

Comment: #1/2 - The endpointID only needs to be unique per UCWA application and technically [application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/application_ref) uniqueness is based on a series of parameters.  Users could have the same endpointId without issue, but as stated could not have the same application data otherwise UCWA returns the existing application instead of creating a new one.

Comment: #3 - It is undocumented, but if you look on the server under IIS for UcwaInt/UcwaExt you should be able to browse the web.config and find a limit related to max applications.  I believe for on-premise this should be ~20.